# How to change language in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04

My pre-installed thunderbird is set to greek language.
I've tried to change it to english with no luck.
Any help would be appriciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

From Thunderbird select:

Edit>Preferences>Composition>Languages then select the language required.

As this seems only to change the language of the spelling selected, the other alternative is to open a terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and enter the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install thunderbird-locale-en-gb
```

With acknowledgements to Mozilla Support Forum https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/trusty/thunderbird-locale-en-gb

Comment: Under Compsition  tab,there are 3 options:General,Addressing,Spelling.

Comment: Under Spelling option there is Language but it's only for spelling!

Comment: @GeorgiosPapadopoulos Thanks for that comment. I have added further information to my posted answer.

Comment: The information you've posted is for version 14.04 and mine is 16.04.